# C: Cannot initialize variable with an rvalue of type void*

Tags: c, pointers, variable-initialization

I have the following code:

```
int *numberArray = calloc(n, sizeof(int));
```

And I am unable to understand why I receive the following error.

```
Cannot initialize a variable of type 'int *' with an rvalue of type 'void *'`.
```

Thank you.

Comment: `int *numberArray = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));` It´s called casting.

Comment: In C++, `malloc` and `calloc` require a type cast.

Comment: Is there no documentation for `calloc` anymore?

Comment: Well, you can also use `new` if it is C++.

Comment: @j809 I replace calloc with new, but now he say: Expected a type

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The compiler's error message is very clear.

The return value of `calloc` is `void*`. You are assigning it to a variable of type `int*`.

That is ok in a C program, but not in a C++ program.

You can change that line to

```
int* numberArray = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
```

But, a better alternative will be to use the `new` operator to allocate memory. After all, you are using C++.

```
int* numberArray = new int[n];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
void* calloc (size_t num, size_t size);
```

> Allocate and zero-initialize array. 
>   Allocates a block of memory for an array of num elements, each of them size bytes long, and initializes all its bits to zero.The effective result is the allocation of a zero-initialized memory block of (num*size) bytes.
>
> On success, a pointer to the memory block allocated by the function.
>   The type of this pointer is always void*, which can be cast to the desired type of data pointer in order to be dereferenceable.
>   If the function failed to allocate the requested block of memory, a null pointer is returned.

To summarize, since `calloc` returns a `void*` (generic pointer) on success of memory allocation, you will have to type-cast it like this in C++:

```
int *numberArray = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
```

If it was C, you can still skip this cast.

Or, use `new` as:

```
int *numberArray = new int [n];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using C memory re-allocation style in a C++ code.
What you want to use is `new` in C++

So your code will become:

```
int n = 10; //n = size of your array
int *narray = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cout << narray[i];
```

Alternatively you can switch back to C and use calloc with casting.

```
int* numberArray = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for calloc is:

void* calloc (size_t num, size_t size);

calloc returns void pointer. In your code , you are trying to assign void pointer to integer pointer. So you are getting Cannot initialize a variable of type 'int *' with an rvalue of type 'void *'. So typecast the void pointer before assign it like this

*numberArray = (int *) calloc(n, sizeof(int));